# Big three implementation in a set class

Tags: c++, set

I am a first year computer science student, and in my assignment i was asked to implement a set class with some basic functions. However it doesn't run properly when i tried to implement the Big three: destructor; copy constructor; copy assignment operator. hope someone can help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int value;          
    Node *next;      
};

class Set {
public:
    Set() { list = nullptr;}  // constructs the empty Set
    bool isEmpty() const;     // returns true if the Set is empty, false otherwise         
    int size() const;         // returns the number of elements in the Set
    bool member(int x) const; // returns true if x is in the Set, false otherwise
    void insert(int x);       // insert x into the Set in ascending order                                   
    // (if x is already in the Set, insert does nothing)
    void remove(int x);       // delete x from the Set                                    
    // (if x is not in the Set, remove does nothing)          
    // the Set, print out like this { 2 5 7 }         
    // returns the union of a and b
    friend ostream & operator <<(ostream &out, const Set& a);
    friend const Set operator +(const Set & a, const Set & b);          // returns the intersection of a and b          
    friend const Set operator *(const Set & a, const Set & b);          // if we create Sets s = {2, 5, 7} and t = {3, 5}          
    // then s + t = {2, 3, 5, 7} and s * t = { 5 }
    Set(const Set &a);
    Set& operator = (const Set &a);     
    ~Set();
private:         
    // The linked list is sorted in ascending order so that the Set          
    // operations union and intersect can be done in linear time using merging.          
    // The insert operation needs to insert x in order but if x is already there,          
    // do not insert it. So the list is always sorted and never has duplicates.         
    Node* list; 
};
bool Set::isEmpty() const{
    if(list == nullptr)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int Set::size() const{
    Node* temp = list;
    int x = 0;
    while(temp != nullptr){
        temp = temp->next;
        x++;
    }
    return x;
}

bool Set::member(int x) const{
    Node* temp = list;
    if(temp == nullptr) return false;
    while(temp != nullptr){
        if(temp->value == x) return true;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return false;
}

void Set::insert(int x){
    Node* temp;
    Node* previous; 

    //create new node
    Node* newNode = new Node; 
    newNode -> value = x;
    newNode -> next = nullptr;    
    if(!member(x)){
        //checking whether the node created is only node or not
        if (list == nullptr) {       
            list = newNode;
        } 
        //If value is less than the value of first node
        else if(x < list->value) {
            newNode -> next = list;
            list = newNode;
        } 
        else {   
            previous = list;
            temp = list -> next;


            //Go to the position where node is to be inserted
            while(temp != nullptr && x > temp -> value) {
                previous = temp;
                temp = temp -> next;
            }
            //Insert the node at particular position
            if(temp == nullptr) {
                previous -> next = newNode;
            } 
            else {
                newNode -> next = temp;
                previous -> next = newNode;
            }
        }
    }
}

ostream& operator << (ostream&out, const Set& a){
    const Node* b = a.list;
    out << "{ ";
    while(b != nullptr){
        out << b->value << " ";
        b = b->next;
    }
    out << "}" << endl;
    return out;
}

void Set::remove(int x){
    if(member(x)){
        if(list == nullptr){
            return;
        }
        else if(list->value == x){
            Node* current = list;
            list = list->next;
            delete current;
        }else{
            Node* previous = list;
            Node* current = list->next;
            while(current != nullptr) {
                if(current->value == x) {
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    previous = current;
                    current = current->next;
                }
            }
            previous->next = current->next;
            delete current;
        }
    }
}

const Set operator +(const Set & a, const Set & b){
    Node* temp1 = a.list;
    Node* temp2 = b.list;
    if(a.list == nullptr) return b;
    if(b.list == nullptr) return a;
    Set c;
    while(temp1 != nullptr && temp2 != nullptr){
        if(temp1->value == temp2->value){
            c.insert(temp1->value);
            temp1 = temp1->next;
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
        else if(temp1->value < temp2->value){
            c.insert(temp1->value);
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        }
        else{
            c.insert(temp2->value);
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
    }
    while(temp1 != nullptr){
        c.insert(temp1->value);
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
    while(temp2 != nullptr){
        c.insert(temp2->value);
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }
    return c;
}
Set::Set (const Set& a){
    Set s;
    Node*temp = a.list;
    while(a.list != nullptr){
        s.insert(temp->value);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
Set& Set::operator = (const Set& a){
    Set s;
    Node*temp = a.list;
    while(a.list != nullptr){
        s.insert(temp->value);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return* this;
}
Set::~Set(){
    Node* curr = list;
    while (list){
        list = list->next;
        delete curr;
        curr = list;
    }
}

const Set operator *(const Set & a, const Set & b){
    Node* temp1 = a.list;
    Node* temp2 = b.list;
    Set c;
    if(a.list == nullptr) return c;
    if(b.list == nullptr) return c;
    while(temp1 != nullptr && temp2 != nullptr){
        if(temp1->value == temp2->value){
            c.insert(temp1->value);
            temp1 = temp1->next;
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
        else if(temp1->value < temp2->value){
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        }
        else{
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
    }

    return c;
}


int main() {      
    Set s, t;     
    cout << "empty set: " << s << "\n";     
    cout << "\texpecting: { }\n";
    cout << "|s|=" << s.size()<< "\n";     
    cout << "\texpecting:|s|= 0\n";     
    s.insert(3);s.insert(1);s.insert(9);s.insert(3);s.insert(7); s.insert(5);     
    cout << "s = " << s << "\n";      
    cout << "\texpecting: s = { 1 3 5 7 9 }\n";     
    if (!s.member(2))
        cout << "2 is not in the set s as expected\n";     
    else        
        cout << "ERROR: 2 is in the set s\n";     
    if (s.member(7))
        cout << "7 is in the set s as expected\n";
    else
        cout << "ERROR: 7 is NOT in the set s\n";
    cout << "|s|=" << s.size()<< "\n";
    cout << "\texpecting:|s|= 5\n";

    s.remove(7); s.remove(1); s.remove(9); s.remove(10);
    cout << "\nafter the removals: s = " << s << "\n";
    cout << "\texpecting: s = { 3 5 }\n";
    s.insert(1); s.insert(7); s.insert(3);
    cout << "with insertions: s = " << s << "\n";
    cout << "\texpecting: s = { 1 3 5 7 }\n";
    t.insert(3); t.insert(5); t.insert(4);
    cout << "with insertions: t = "<< t << "\n";
    Set a = s + t;
    cout << "s union t = " << a << "\n";
    s.remove(3); t.remove(4);
    cout << "remove 3: s = " << s << "\n";
    cout << "remove 4: t = " << t << "\n";
    s.insert(3); t.insert(4);
    cout << "insert 3: s = " << s << "\n";
    cout << "insert 4: t = " << t << "\n";
    Set b = s * t;
    cout << "s intersect t = " << b << "\n";
    cout << "s = " << s << "\n";
    cout << "t = " << t << "\n";

    s.~Set();
    cout << "s = " << s << "\n";
    cout << "\texpecting: s = { }\n";
    return 0; 

}
```

I expect the output of {1 3 4 5 7} from

```
Set a = s + t;
cout << "s union t = " << a << "\n";
```

However once i implement the destuctor, it gives one-set of three random number non-stop, as shown below

s union t = { 7107856 7106168 7078080 7107856 7106168 7078080 7107856 7106168 7078080 7107856 7106168 7078080 7107856 7106168 7078080 7107856 7106168 7078080 7107856 7106168 7078080 7107856 7106168 7078080 7107856 7106168 7078080 7107856 7106168 7078080 7107856 7106168 7078080 7107856 7106168 7078080 7107856 7106168 7078080 7107856 7106168 7078080 7107856 7106168 7078080 7107856 7106168 7078080 7107856 7106168 7078080 7107856 7106168 7078080

Comment: You only implemented the destructor as far as we can tell. Where is your implementation of copy constructor and copy assignment operator you mentioned?

Comment: `friend const Set operator +` -- This (and the `operator *`) will not work correctly until you implement working, non-buggy, copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor.   You're returning a `Set` by value, thus the type must have correct copy semantics.

Comment: Also, why are you doing this: `s.~Set();`?  Do not call the destructor directly.

Comment: And turn on more warnings. The compiler will give you a lot of hints for this code.

Comment: O.T.: `Set() { list = nullptr;}  // constructs the empty Set` is construction with assignment of member `list`. Construction with member construction would be `Set(): list(nullptr) { }`. It's more idiomatic and that for a reason: For more complex member types, your style would result in member with default construction and assign while mine is member construction only.

Comment: O.T.: `bool Set::isEmpty() const { if (list == nullptr) return true; else return false; }` can be abbreviated to `bool Set::isEmpty() const { return list == nullptr; }`. The `operator==()` already returns a `bool` which you can return directly - no need for the extra `if`.

Comment: i have just implement the copy constructor and the assignment operator. Did I implement them correctly?

Comment: Your copy constructor should have signature `Set(const Set&)`. The assignment as well `Set& operator=(const Set&)`. What you did will not be recognized as copy constructor...

Comment: `Set(const vector& a);` is not a copy constructor. It's just a regular constructor, which takes an argument. Perhaps you should revisit lesson about copy constructors and the Rule of Three?

Comment: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f601288d9d3dfa2). As you can see, copying works although no proper copy constructor defined. That's because the compiler adds one but this is the one which won't work properly in your case (as well as mine).

Comment: Maybe in your cpy-ctor and assignment operator implementation you've member-wise copy rather than deep-copy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is apparent: you are overloading the copy constructor while maybe you meant implementing copy-constructor and assignment operator:

```
Set(const vector& a); // constructor that take a const reference to std::vector. not a copy constructor.
operator = (const vector& a); // should be Set(const Set&);
```

so as long as you've not provided copy constructor and assignment operator then the compiler will synthesize them for you. So by default they do `a shallow copy` or `member-wise copy` not a `deep copy`.

So in your example you are not acquiring rule of three.

- The interface may look like:

  ```
  class Set{
      public:
          Set(); // default constructor
          Set(const Set&); // copy constructor
          Set& operator=(const Set&); // assignemnt operator
          ~Set();// destructor

  };
  ```
- Also `std::vector` is a template class container thus you should specify the element type otherwise it is compile-time error.
- Also the assignment operator must return value so you cannot declare it without return type.
- What is the point in creating a local `Node` in copy constructor:

  ```
  Set::Set(const Set& a) {
      Set s; // local
      Node*temp = a.list;
      while (a.list != nullptr) {
          s.insert(temp->value);
          temp = temp->next;
      }
      // s is destructed here
  }
  ```
- You should not call the destructor explicitly because in main you do so:

  ```
      s.~Set();// call dtor explicitly
  ```

Because after `s` gets out of scope its `dtor` is called automatically thus calling destructor twice may cause an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with the assignment

```
Set a = s + t
```

In the class definition of Set there is no overloaded assignment "=" operator. You can define a member function like `Set& operator=(const Set& rhs_set);` and provide the respective definition so that the behavior can be defined. The function can be like this.

```
Set& operator=(const Set &a) {
    Node* temp = a.list;
    while (temp != nullptr) {
        insert (temp->value);
        temp = temp->next;

    }
    return *this;
}
```

I have tried this with some little tweaks in your code.

Hope this helps, Thanks

Comment: You forgot to clear out the current values held by `this`. This just adds more values.

Comment: Yeah, good catch @Ted Lyngmo. We can add one more member function to clear all the elements in the set and deallocate the memory. And call that function here so that it'll not cause any other problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has been pointed out yet, but your copy constructor is wrong. In this code

```
Set::Set (const Set& a){
    Set s;
    Node*temp = a.list;
    while(a.list != nullptr){
        s.insert(temp->value);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

you are copying from `a` to `s`. Obviously that not what you should do, `s` is just some local variable that's going to get destroyed when the copy constructor exits. You should copy from `a` to `*this`. Like this

```
Set::Set(const Set& a) {
    Node* temp = a.list;
    while (a.list != nullptr) {
        insert(temp->value);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```